# Django 1.8, Using Admin app as the main site

Tags: python, django

I am about to begin work on a project that will use Django to create a system with three tiers of users. Each user will login into the dashboard type interface (each user will have different types of tools on the dashboard). There will be a few CRUD type interfaces for each user tier among other things. Only users with accounts will be able to interact with the system (anyone visiting is greeted with a login screen).

It seems that many people recommend to simply modify the default Admin app to fit the requirements. Is this an ideal solution and if so, how do I set so the admin interface is at the site's root (instead of admin/). Also, any documentation on in-depth and secure modification of the admin interface (along with the addition of different user tiers) would be appreciated.

Comment: try these apps: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/admin-interface/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea.

Out of the box, the information architecture presented by the admin interface is going to be very flat where views essentially mirror what's in the database 1:1. I can imagine a slim subset of users in internal IT apps or similar where that may be appropriate but the compromises in usability are serious, without modifying the admin interface so much that you'll probably wish you had done your app the traditional way by the time you were done.

If usability and information architecture are not serious concerns or requirements for your app, then you may proceed apace.

Comment: Do you have any resources on a good way to utilize Django's Auth system for creating my custom admin/user dashboard system?

Comment: We use django rules which is light and easy-to-use: https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules

Comment: I'd also recommend studying RBAC a bit before committing to an auth system. That said, many django extensions will rely on the app using the default django auth system, so there are definite advantages to sticking to vanilla django and avoiding franken-django. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control

Comment: I think this is good advice, I will probably utilize Django's user/group for the log in system and the 'django-rules' system for more finite controls (like a user only being able to CRUD their documents). Do you have any current information on extending the basic User class to add a few additional fields?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to remove `admin`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/$', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Tried this, but when navigating to localhost:8000/ it just gave me the django default page with the 'no urls are configured' type message